# Apply function to dataframe with changing argument

Tags: r, apply

I have 2 objects:

A data frame with 3 variables:

```
v1 <- 1:10
v2 <- 11:20
v3 <- 21:30
df <- data.frame(v1,v2,v3)
```

A numeric vector with 3 elements:

```
nv <- c(6,11,28)
```

I would like to compare the first variable to the first number, the second variable to the second number and so on.

```
which(df$v1 > nv[1])
which(df$v2 > nv[2])
which(df$v3 > nv[3])
```

Of course in reality my data frame has a lot more variables so manually typing each variable is not an option.

I encounter these kinds of problems quite frequently. What kind of documentation would I need to read to be fluent in these matters?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option would be to compare with equally sized elements.  For this we can replicate the elements in 'nv' each by number of rows of 'df' (`rep(nv, each=nrow(df))`) and compare with `df` or use the `col` function that does similar output as `rep`.

```
 which(df > nv[col(df)], arr.ind=TRUE)
```

If you need a logical matrix that corresponds to comparison of each column with each element of 'nv'

```
 sweep(df, 2, nv, FUN='>')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. All of these are great answers by the way.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use `mapply`:

```
mapply(FUN=function(x, y)which(x > y), x=df, y=nv)
#$v1
#[1]  7  8  9 10
#
#$v2
#[1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
#
#$v3
#[1]  9 10
```

Answer (score 3):

I think these sorts of situations are tricky because normal looping solutions (e.g. the `apply` function) only loop through one object, but you need to loop both through `df` and `nv` simultaneously. One approach is to loop through the indices and to use them to grab the appropriate information from both `df` and `nv`. A convenient way to loop through indices is the `sapply` function:

```
sapply(seq_along(nv), function(x) which(df[,x] > nv[x]))
# [[1]]
# [1]  7  8  9 10
# 
# [[2]]
# [1]  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
# 
# [[3]]
# [1]  9 10
```